# If Date equals Date Else

Tags: python

This should work! It's simple... yet here I am. Is my syntax wrong somewhere?

```py
for row in dbOps(sqlQuery, "", "SELECT"):
    rowDate = row['d_date']
    currDate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(rowDate, currDate)
    if rowDate == currDate:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")

#### Output
2020-02-19 2020-02-19
no
```

Edit:
When I run this as string literals, it works...?

```py
rowDate = "2020-02-19"
currDate = "2020-02-19"
print(rowDate, currDate)
if rowDate == currDate:
  print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: check type of data - `print( type(rowDate), type(currDate) )` - maybe you don't have two strings.

Comment: `<class 'datetime.date'> <class 'str'>` You're right! What should I use to format `currdate` in my desired way while keeping its `type`?

Comment: use `rowDate = rowDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`  or check what will happend when you keep `currDate = datetime.datetime.today()`

Comment: @furas `rowDate = row['d_date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` worked, now that they are both strings. Thanks for your help. Could you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should check type of data

```
print( type(rowDate), type(currDate) )
```

Maybe you don't have two strings.

if you have dateiem then you can use

```
rowDate = rowDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

or you can check what will happen if keep

```
currDate = datetime.datetime.today()
```

---

If `rowDate` is `datetime.date` then try

```
currDate = datetime.datetime.today().date()
```

or

```
currDate = datetime.date.today()
```